# Aplying FFT to Wav file data

Tags: fft, c++

Technology: C++, CodeBlocks IDE.

I've just read sample wav file (source - http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2015-12-13_4694675918641206/movies/2001/daisy.wav ) with an txt output (https://paste.ee/p/pXGvm), which i get from using this code:

```
    WavAnalysis wav_analyse;
    static const uint16_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::cout << "Buffering data... " << std::endl;
    fseek(wavFile, 44, SEEK_SET); // skip header data
    while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], BUFFER_SIZE / (sizeof buffer[0]), wavFile)) > 0)
    {
        //do sth with buffer data
        wav_analyse.FFT(buffer); // currently shows data only
    }
```

Wav file header informations:

- 1 channel PCM,
- 8 bits per sample,
- sampling rate is 11025Hz.

In next step I'm normalising values to the range of [-1;1) with function:

```
float WavAnalysis::normaliseValuetoFloat(uint8_t value){
    float normalisedValue = (float)value;
    normalisedValue -= 128;
    normalisedValue /= 128;
    return normalisedValue;
}
```

My goal is to create my own library for voice activity detection, now I'm working on FFT module. I need this data to calculate signal energy and its entropy in chosen signal parts.

---

**updates:**

After reading commented sources, I've learned that average and sufficient length of data for feeding FFT algorythm is 1024 (or any other that is equal to power of two).

**Question now:** FFT changes signal domain from time (real values) to frequency (which contains complex numbers). Why does available sources populates the FFT algorithm with complex array? Ex.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121574/safe-and-fast-fft

Comment: You should be more specific about your programming environment, after having done your research, with these links: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/preparations-to-implement-fft-on-a-wav-file-code-java-not-library?rq=1, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19422/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-a-wav-file-before-calculating-the-fft?rq=1

Comment: Also: please clarify what do you mean by "with an txt output".

Comment: @MBaz, the second linked file is a printout of each 8-bit sample value as ascii.

Comment: That isn't likely to work. The data is encoded as integers in offset binary.

Comment: Also, from your code, you seem to be reading the wav file's header as data.

Answer (score 1):

Your FFT code initializes a complex array because that is what the Fourier Transform produces. You should understand the [complex exponential](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8482/what-is-the-role-of-complex-exponential/8483#8483), and the nature of the transform as a change of basis (i.e. a projection onto a basis of sines & cosines).

It is a big topic that is well travelled, start here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304532/why-does-fft-produce-complex-numbers-instead-of-real-numbers